# Declaring a NSString, should it first be set to nil, not set at all or init and alloc?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I have this code:

```
int tag = ...
NSString *url;
if(tag==1){
    url = @"login";
}
else {
    url = @"register";
}
```

I want to declare the `NSString` var before I know what its value is. What is better?:

```
NSString *url; // option 1
```

or

```
NSString url = nil;  // option 2
```

or

```
NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] init];  // option 3
```

Wondering what is the common practice and what are the advantages and disadvantages for each?

Comment: If you are using ARC the best practice is to declare like: NSString *url; Since this will automatically convert to nil and you don't have to reassign it again to nil.

Comment: Using a variable names `url` for a string is a really bad idea, what will you name the variable that really is a url? Naming matters.

Comment: Option 2 is not really an option, it's just a bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelDorner What? Option 2 is an option and it is not a bad idea. Why do you say that?

Comment: @rmaddy Because interface types cannot be statically allocated; in other word: `NSString url = nil;` should be `NSString *url = nil` - please fix this potential typo!

Comment: @MichaelDorner Oh I see.  The missing asterisk appears to be a typo. I didn't notice that when I made my comment.

Comment: Just to comment on option 3: this is semantically different as it always holds a real string object. Basically one string is created and then immediately destroyed (it actually might be a singleton here, but that's a different matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Best practice:**

```
NSString * url = nil;
```

**But in your case you can do though it is complex.**

```
NSString * url = tag==1 ? @"login" : @"register";
```

Comment: I disagree with the line you marked as "best practice". Under ARC object variables are implicitly set to `nil` if there is no initial value.

Comment: who says he is using ARC?

Comment: These days we consider that ARC is being used unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: If the OP isn't then he/she should be.

Comment: ARC sometimes can't relase when an object fall into loop.

Comment: @jamil65able what is the name of the syntax used on your second example? i.e. NSString * url = tag==1 ? @"login" : @"register";

Comment: But if i question you what will be the disadvantage(i.e memory loss, crash can occure) of assinging nil to a varible?Obviously, no answer. So best is best.

Comment: this is one kind of if-else statement of C language support most of the languages(Objc c, c, c++, Java)

Comment: @MichaelDorner No, that is not short circuit evaluation. That's something completely different. The `?:` syntax is the "ternary operator".

Comment: @Abizern But many people consider being explicit a much better practice than relying on an implicit behavior. Many of us have been programming LONG before ARC came along and started initializing local variables as `nil`. So being explicit is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @KexAri The `?:` syntax is the standard "ternary operator". Objective-C gets that from C.

Comment: @rmaddy My disagreement that it was universally considered "best practice" In the same way that I disagree that CocoaPods is the "de-facto dependency manager for Cocoa". I'm not saying it's bad, just that not everyone does it that way.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [Apple's documentation tells us](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW5):

> **Stack Variables Are Initialized with `nil`**
>
> Using ARC, strong, weak, and
>   autoreleasing stack variables are now implicitly initialized with `nil`.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> - (void)myMethod {
>     NSString *name;
>     NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
> }
> ```
>
> will log null for the value of name rather than perhaps crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Initialising variables is good practice.
Not only does it prevent bugs, if you always do it you don't need to worry about whether it's necessary and can instead think about more important things.

You need to initialise with a sensible value though; your third variant allocates a `NSString` only to immediately discard it, so it's a very bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

For your use case best practice is to use

```
NSString * url = nil;
```

I believe ARC does this for you, but its always good to be explicit.